# Using SELECT .. AS in a Python Sqlite query

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

In SQLite3, I have a "Accounts" table.  I can run any of these queries:

```sql
SELECT Last_Bal AS Balance FROM Accounts;
SELECT Last_Bal AS 'Balance' FROM Accounts;
SELECT Last_Bal as "Balance" FROM Accounts;
```

All three queries run fine, and display the word "Balance" as the column heading.

However, when I run this code in Python 3:

```
c.Execute( 'SELECT Last_Bal AS Balance FROM Accounts' )
```

I get the error message: "sqlite3.OperationalError: near "Balance": syntax error".  If I try putting single quotes or double quotes around the word Balance, as in this:

```
c.Execute( 'SELECT Last_Bal AS "Balance" FROM Accounts' )
```

I get the error message: "_tkinter.TclError: Invalid column index Balance"

I've tried swapping the single quotes for double quotes, and even triple quotes, but nothing seems to work.

SOLVED:  Stupid User Error - I was using two different SELECT statements trying to build a TreeView. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What *type* of objects is `c`? Also, does the TclError occur at that line or later on?

Comment: `conn = sqlite3.connect('C:\Checkbook.db')
c = conn.cursor()`
So, to answer your question, I presume c is a cursor.

Comment: That makes sense (although it should be `.execute` not `.Execute`), which makes me suspect of the next error message being raised at the given location.

Comment: What does [`Row.keys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Row.keys) show for the result?